# Show total price on a product page when the quantity is changed. Product with discount rules! WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I'm working on a WooCommerce shop, and I want to show the Total Price on the product page, just below the add to cart button. All the codes I found do that based on the original price, not the discounted price. To calculate the discount, I'm using pricing rules and the plugin is "Advanced Dynamic Pricing for WooCommerce".

```
/* Calculate Subtotal Based on Quantity - WooCommerce Single Product */

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'bbloomer_product_price_recalculate' );
 
function bbloomer_product_price_recalculate() {
   global $product;
   echo '<div id="subtot" style="display:inline-block;">Total: <span></span></div>';
   $price = $product->get_price();
   $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
   wc_enqueue_js( "      
      $('[name=quantity]').on('input change', function() { 
         var qty = $(this).val();
         var price = '" . esc_js( $price ) . "';
         var price_string = (price*qty).toFixed(2);
         $('#subtot > span').html('" . esc_js( $currency ) . "'+price_string);
      }).change();
   " );
}
```

This code works, but it doesn't take into account the pricing rules.

[image: Example for the Total Price on the Product Page - WooCommerce]

Thank you!

I tried adding this code I found (Calculate Subtotal Based on Quantity), but it doesn't work with the pricing rules. I tried a few plugins for dynamic pricing, and always I get the original product price multiplied with the quantity. It doesn't take into account the pricing rules.

Comment: The problem is related with the plugin Advanced Dynamic Pricing for WooCommerce. The code you shared is correct, since get_price() returns the active price of the product. You may try another plugin or add a workaround to your code by checking how the plugin applies discounts.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @MrEbabi. I tried with a few plugins, but nothing worked. I can't do the workaround sadly. 

Since I couldn't find a solution, I may need to hire somebody to write the PHP function or jQuery code (if possible with that as somebody suggested).